# Index of files to backup

Tags: file, database, indexing

I'm looking for something similar to http://www.indexyourfiles.com/ for the mac.

What I want to do is create a backup of my file index which is portable and can be searched through even if you don't have actual access to the files.

Any clues?

Br

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of "disk catalogs" on [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com) revealed some of the apps that used to be much more common. [NeoFinder](http://www.cdfinder.de/index.html) (formerly CDFinder) and [Disk Catalog Maker](http://diskcatalogmaker.com) 
were well-rated. A search of the Mac App Store would I'm sure turn up more, though they all seem to have become more expensive.